# Why some apt-get and aptitude installations remove some programs?

Tags: linux, debian, installation, apt, aptitude

I wanted to install wireshark, and I went to [Installing wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/ChBuildInstallUnixInstallBins.html)
So I just typed on terminal `aptitude install wireshark` and before it install wireshark, it removed 251 programs, and I don't have basic programs on my computer.

This is a snippet of output:

```
Removendo aisleriot ...
Removendo ant-optional ...
Removendo ant ...
Removendo argyll ...
Removendo at-spi2-core ...
Removendo baobab ...
Removendo browser-plugin-gnash ...
Removendo caribou-antler ...
Removendo caribou ...
Removendo cheese ...
Removendo gdm3 ...
Removendo dconf-tools ...
Removendo empathy ...
Removendo nautilus-sendto-empathy ...
Removendo empathy-common ...
Removendo gnome-orca ...
Removendo speech-dispatcher ...
speech-dispatcher disabled; edit /etc/default/speech-dispatcher
Removendo libespeak1:amd64 ...
Removendo espeak-data:amd64 ...
Removendo file-roller ...
Removendo gnome-nettool ...
Removendo finger ...
Removendo fonts-cantarell ...
Removendo fonts-sil-gentium ...
Removendo libreoffice ...
Removendo ttf-sil-gentium-basic ...
Removendo fonts-sil-gentium-basic ...
Removendo gcalctool ...
Removendo gdebi ...
Removendo gedit-plugins ...
Removendo gedit ...
Removendo gedit-common ...
Removendo python-pyatspi2 ...
Removendo python-pyatspi ...
Removendo gir1.2-atspi-2.0 ...
Removendo gnome-documents ...
Removendo gir1.2-gdata-0.0 ...
Removendo rhythmbox-plugins ...
Removendo gir1.2-gnomekeyring-1.0 ...
Removendo gir1.2-goa-1.0 ...
Removendo gnome-shell-extensions ...
Removendo gir1.2-gtop-2.0 ...
Removendo gir1.2-gucharmap-2.90 ...
Removendo gir1.2-webkit-3.0 ...
Removendo gir1.2-javascriptcoregtk-3.0 ...
Removendo gir1.2-rb-3.0 ...
Removendo gir1.2-tracker-0.14 ...
Removendo gir1.2-wnck-3.0 ...
Removendo gnome-games ...
Removendo glchess ...
Removendo glines ...
Removendo gnash ...
Removendo gnash-common ...
Removendo gnect ...
Removendo gnibbles ...
Removendo gnobots2 ...
Removendo gnome-backgrounds ...
Removendo gnome-color-manager ...
Removendo gnome-dictionary ...
Removendo gnome-disk-utility ...
Removendo gnome-font-viewer ...
Removendo swell-foop ...
Removendo quadrapassel ...
Removendo mahjongg ...
Removendo lightsoff ...
Removendo iagno ...
Removendo gtali ...
Removendo gnotski ...
Removendo gnotravex ...
Removendo gnomine ...
Removendo gnome-sudoku ...
Removendo gnome-games-data ...
Removendo gnome-games-extra-data ...
Removendo gnome-icon-theme-extras ...
Removendo gnome-mag ...
Removendo gnome-packagekit ...
Removendo gnome-packagekit-data ...
Removendo gnome-screenshot ...
Removendo gnome-system-log ...
Removendo gnome-tweak-tool ...
Removendo gnome-video-effects ...
Removendo gnuchess-book ...
Removendo gnuchess ...
Removendo grilo-plugins-0.1:amd64 ...
Removendo gucharmap ...
Removendo guile-2.0-libs ...
Removendo hamster-applet ...
Removendo hyphen-en-us ...
Removendo inkscape ...
Removendo iputils-tracepath ...
Removendo libcommons-digester-java ...
Removendo libcommons-beanutils-java ...
Removendo libcommons-logging-java ...
Removendo libcommons-parent-java ...
Removendo libapache-pom-java ...
Removendo python-gnome2 ...
Removendo libgnomeui-0 ...
Removendo libbonoboui2-0 ...
Removendo libgnomecanvas2-0 ...
Removendo libart-2.0-2:amd64 ...
Removendo libatk-adaptor:amd64 ...
Removendo libatk-adaptor-data ...
Removendo libatk-bridge2.0-0:amd64 ...
Removendo libatspi1.0-0 ...
Removendo libatspi2.0-0:amd64 ...
Removendo vinagre ...
Removendo telepathy-salut ...
Removendo libavahi-gobject0:amd64 ...
Removendo libgdu-gtk0 ...
Removendo libavahi-ui-gtk3-0:amd64 ...
Removendo libblas3gf ...
Removendo libbonoboui2-common ...
Removendo libboost-program-options1.49.0 ...
Removendo libboost-thread1.49.0 ...
Removendo xbrlapi ...
Removendo python-brlapi ...
Removendo libbrlapi0.5:amd64 ...
Removendo libcaribou-gtk-module:amd64 ...
Removendo libcaribou-gtk3-module:amd64 ...
Removendo libreoffice-calc ...
Removendo lp-solve ...
Removendo libcolamd2.7.1 ...
Removendo libcolorblind0 ...
Removendo libcommons-collections3-java ...
Removendo libcommons-compress-java ...
Removendo libdb-java ...
Removendo libdb-je-java ...
Removendo libdb5.1-java ...
Removendo libdb5.1-java-jni:amd64 ...
Removendo zeitgeist-core ...
Removendo libdee-1.0-4 ...
Removendo sound-juicer ...
Removendo libdiscid0:amd64 ...
Removendo libdmapsharing-3.0-2 ...
Removendo libdotconf1.0 ...
Removendo libgail-common:amd64 ...
Removendo libgdict-1.0-6 ...
Removendo libgdict-common ...
Removendo libgeocode-glib0 ...
Removendo shotwell ...
Removendo libgexiv2-1 ...
Removendo libglade2-0 ...
Removendo libgnome-mag2 ...
Removendo libgnomecanvas2-common ...
Removendo libgnomeui-common ...
Removendo libgpod-common ...
Removendo libgpod4:amd64 ...
Removendo libgrilo-0.1-0:amd64 ...
Removendo libgtk-vnc-2.0-0 ...
Removendo libgtkmm-2.4-1c2a ...
Removendo rygel-tracker ...
Removendo rygel-preferences ...
Removendo rygel-playbin ...
Removendo rygel ...
Removendo libgupnp-av-1.0-2 ...
Removendo libgupnp-dlna-1.0-2 ...
Removendo libgvnc-1.0-0 ...
Removendo libreoffice-report-builder-bin ...
Removendo libreoffice-evolution ...
Removendo libreoffice-base ...
Removendo libhsqldb-java ...
Removendo libicc2:amd64 ...
Removendo libicu4j-java ...
Removendo libimdi0:amd64 ...
Removendo libreoffice-filter-mobiledev ...
Removendo libreoffice-java-common ...
Removendo libxalan2-java ...
Removendo libjaxp1.3-java ...
Removendo libjline-java ...
Removendo libjtidy-java ...
Removendo liblinear-tools ...
Removendo nmap ...
Removendo liblinear1 ...
Removendo python-louis ...
Removendo liblouis2:amd64 ...
Removendo liblouis-data ...
Removendo liblucene2-java ...
Removendo pstoedit ...
Removendo libpstoedit0c2a ...
Removendo libmagick++5:amd64 ...
Removendo transmission-gtk ...
Removendo libminiupnpc5 ...
Removendo libmtp-runtime ...
Removendo libmtp9:amd64 ...
Removendo libmtp-common ...
Removendo libnatpmp1 ...
Removendo libplot2c2 ...
Removendo libraw5:amd64 ...
Removendo libregexp-java ...
Removendo libreoffice-help-en-us ...
Removendo libreoffice-writer ...
Removendo libreoffice-base-core ...
Removendo libreoffice-impress ...
Removendo libreoffice-draw ...
Removendo libreoffice-emailmerge ...
Removendo libreoffice-filter-binfilter ...
Removendo libreoffice-gnome ...
Removendo libreoffice-gtk ...
Removendo libreoffice-math ...
Removendo rhythmbox-plugin-cdrecorder ...
Removendo rhythmbox ...
Removendo librhythmbox-core6 ...
Removendo libservlet2.5-java ...
Removendo telepathy-rakia ...
Removendo libsofia-sip-ua-glib3 ...
Removendo libsofia-sip-ua0 ...
Removendo libsonic0:amd64 ...
Removendo libspeechd2 ...
Removendo libsvm-tools ...
Removendo libtelepathy-farstream2:amd64 ...
Removendo libunique-3.0-0 ...
Removendo libvisio-0.0-0 ...
Removendo python-wnck ...
Removendo libwnck22 ...
Removendo libwnck-common ...
Removendo libwps-0.2-2 ...
Removendo libwpg-0.2-2 ...
Removendo libwpd-0.9-9 ...
Removendo libxerces2-java ...
Removendo libxml-commons-external-java ...
Removendo libxml-commons-resolver1.1-java ...
Removendo libxz-java ...
Removendo media-player-info ...
Removendo minissdpd ...
Removendo mobile-broadband-provider-info ...
Removendo mythes-en-us ...
Removendo network-manager-gnome ...
Removendo p7zip-full ...
Removendo perlmagick ...
Removendo python-gconf ...
Removendo python-mako ...
Removendo python-markupsafe ...
Removendo python-notify ...
Removendo python-pyorbit ...
Removendo python-speechd ...
Removendo unoconv ...
Removendo python-uno ...
Removendo python-zeitgeist ...
Removendo rdesktop ...
Removendo rhythmbox-data ...
Removendo seahorse ...
Removendo shotwell-common ...
Removendo simple-scan ...
Removendo sound-theme-freedesktop ...
Removendo telepathy-gabble ...
Removendo telepathy-idle ...
Removendo telepathy-logger ...
Removendo transmission-common ...
Removendo ttf-liberation ...
Removendo vino ...
Removendo xdg-user-dirs-gtk ...
Processando gatilhos para menu ...
Processando gatilhos para hicolor-icon-theme ...
Processando gatilhos para man-db ...
Processando gatilhos para libglib2.0-0:amd64 ...
Processando gatilhos para gconf2 ...
Processando gatilhos para desktop-file-utils ...
Processando gatilhos para gnome-menus ...
Processando gatilhos para python-support ...
Processando gatilhos para install-info ...
Processando gatilhos para fontconfig ...
Processando gatilhos para mime-support ...
Processando gatilhos para shared-mime-info ...
Processando gatilhos para gnome-icon-theme ...
A seleccionar pacote anteriormente não seleccionado libsmi2ldbl:amd64.
(Lendo banco de dados ... 107762 ficheiros e directórios actualmente instalados.)
Desempacotando libsmi2ldbl:amd64 (de .../libsmi2ldbl_0.4.8+dfsg2-7_amd64.deb) ...
A seleccionar pacote anteriormente não seleccionado libc-ares2:amd64.
Desempacotando libc-ares2:amd64 (de .../libc-ares2_1.9.1-3_amd64.deb) ...
A seleccionar pacote anteriormente não seleccionado libwireshark-data.
Desempacotando libwireshark-data (de .../libwireshark-data_1.8.2-5wheezy14_all.deb) ...
A seleccionar pacote anteriormente não seleccionado libwsutil2.
Desempacotando libwsutil2 (de .../libwsutil2_1.8.2-5wheezy14_amd64.deb) ...
A seleccionar pacote anteriormente não seleccionado libwiretap2.
Desempacotando libwiretap2 (de .../libwiretap2_1.8.2-5wheezy14_amd64.deb) ...
A seleccionar pacote anteriormente não seleccionado libwireshark2.
Desempacotando libwireshark2 (de .../libwireshark2_1.8.2-5wheezy14_amd64.deb) ...
A seleccionar pacote anteriormente não seleccionado wireshark-common.
Desempacotando wireshark-common (de .../wireshark-common_1.8.2-5wheezy14_amd64.deb) ...
A seleccionar pacote anteriormente não seleccionado wireshark.
Desempacotando wireshark (de .../wireshark_1.8.2-5wheezy14_amd64.deb) ...
Processando gatilhos para man-db ...
Processando gatilhos para desktop-file-utils ...
Processando gatilhos para gnome-menus ...
Processando gatilhos para hicolor-icon-theme ...
Processando gatilhos para menu ...
Configurando libsmi2ldbl:amd64 (0.4.8+dfsg2-7) ...
Configurando libc-ares2:amd64 (1.9.1-3) ...
Configurando libwireshark-data (1.8.2-5wheezy14) ...
Configurando libwsutil2 (1.8.2-5wheezy14) ...
Configurando libwiretap2 (1.8.2-5wheezy14) ...
Configurando libwireshark2 (1.8.2-5wheezy14) ...
Configurando wireshark-common (1.8.2-5wheezy14) ...
Configurando wireshark (1.8.2-5wheezy14) ...
Processando gatilhos para menu ...

Estado atual: 67 atualizados [-18].
```

Why this occur ?

Comment: Probably at some point you removed a (meta-?)package (like, gnome) which lead to a bunch of packages that are no longer needed, and being auto-installed (as dependencies) they will now be autoremoved as unused.

Comment: @Dan But, why they are being removed ? I still use them.

Comment: Because it's a computer, it does what it's programmed to do. If you remove at some point a needed meta package, it's like trying to break the system. The computer will happily do so.

Comment: Show the command you ran and the complete output.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I ran this command: `aptitude install wireshark`, I deleted the output, sorry, but it had a few lines more than above. All programs that were uninstalled that I need, I installed again.